# php page to insert data to sql not working

Tags: php, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to add data to my sql server from a Unity game through a php. The php code is given below. The URL I'm testing with is

The SQL server as well as the php file is hosted in Azure, I have been able to add data through standard SQL commands etc(database connection is working properly), and running the following page when tested with the URL http://example.net/filename.php?one=4&two=8 only returns Test84, and no change is made to the table.

I would really appreciate it if someone is able to tell me as to why this is not working

```
    <?php 
// 
echo"Test";
$data=$_GET[one];
$data1=$_GET[two];
echo $data1;
echo $data;
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = {}; Database = {}", "{}", "{}");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$sql = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO registratib_tbl (name,email ) VALUES ( ? , ?)");
$sql->bindParam(1, $data);  
$sql->bindParam(2, $data1);  
$sql->execute();  

//$conn->query($sql); 
echo "<h3>Data Inserted!</h3>"; 

?>
```

Comment: Did you try $_GET["one"] instead of $_GET[one]?? are the values echoed correctly?

Comment: yes, they are echoed correctly

Comment: VALUE ( ? , ?)  to VALUES ( ? , ?) --- you missed the S there.

Comment: @KarloKokkak it's perfectly valid in mysql, should the OP be using MySQL. I had a feeling someone would mention something about that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html - `{VALUES | VALUE}`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Okay. I didn't know that. Thanks for that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think OP is using sql server..

Comment: @Khan ah right you are.

Comment: @KarloKokkak well.... in mysql it's valid, so mssql stand to be what they need to use here, as you stated. But.. in mysql, both are valid.

Comment: I tried it after changing it to VALUES, still the same thing

Comment: Use `try { $sql->execute(); } catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` to see if there is any exception from database.

Comment: @Furgas I've tried doing that. No change in the result. The resulting page still shows Test84

Comment: Move `try {` before `new PDO` and examine return value of `prepare` and `bindParam` - they will return `FALSE` in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to insert data as shown below:

```
 <?php

 $serverName = "tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433";
 $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"yourdatabase",
 "Uid"=>"yourusername", "PWD"=>"yourpassword");
 //Establishes the connection
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
 //Select Query
 $tsql = "SELECT [CompanyName] FROM SalesLT.Customer";
 //Executes the query
 $getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
 //Error handling
 if ($getProducts == FALSE)
 die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
 $productCount = 0;
 $ctr = 0;
 ?> 
 <h1> First 10 results are : </h1>
 <?php
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 { 
 if($ctr>9)
 break; 
 $ctr++;
 echo($row['CompanyName']);
 echo("<br/>");
 $productCount++;
 }
 sqlsrv_free_stmt($getProducts);

 $tsql = "INSERT SalesLT.Product (Name, ProductNumber, StandardCost, ListPrice, SellStartDate) OUTPUT INSERTED.ProductID VALUES ('SQL New 1', 'SQL New 2', 0, 0, getdate())";
 //Insert query
 $insertReview = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
 if($insertReview == FALSE)
 die(FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors()));
 ?> 
 <h1> Product Key inserted is :</h1> 
 <?php
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($insertReview, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 { 
 echo($row['ProductID']);
 }
 sqlsrv_free_stmt($insertReview);
 //Delete Query
 //We are deleting the same record
 $tsql = "DELETE FROM [SalesLT].[Product] WHERE Name=?";
 $params = array("SQL New 1");

 $deleteReview = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, $params);
 if($deleteReview == FALSE)
 die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

 if(sqlsrv_execute($deleteReview) == FALSE)
 die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

 ?>
```

For more information, please visit [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2015/05/11/getting-started-with-php-5-6-and-microsoft-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database/) article.